# where to put the log4j.properties file in a spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, log4j

I have created a `log4j.properties` file, and I have put it in the resources folder as the `application.properties` file, in this file I have this line : `logging.config=log4j.properties` which indicated the name of my log4j properties file, but when I run my application I'm getting this error on my console :

```
Logging system failed to initialize using configuration from 'log4j.properties'
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\***\Desktop\CapRecrute\log4j.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

so I tried to change the `logging.config` property to `src\\main\\resources\\log4j.properties`, and then I got another error :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize Logback logging from src\main\resources\log4j.properties ... Caused by: ch.qos.logback.core.LogbackException: Unexpected filename extension of file [file:/C:/Users/Aimad%20MAJDOU/Desktop/CapRecrute/src/main/resources/log4j.properties]. Should be either .groovy or .xml
```

in my pom file I have this :

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

How can I solve this ?

Comment: Have you read through this: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html

Answer (score 3):

The simplest thing is to use Spring's Logback. You just need to add these 2 lines to `application.properties`

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate=ERROR
```

and make sure there are no other logging related lines.

If you instead want log4j, then configure so in your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And then in your paplication.properties:

```
logging.path=/tmp/logs/
logging.file=/tmp/logs/myapplog.log
logging.config=log4j.properties
```

Also make sure log4j is in the root of your project (not under resources).

Comment: Hey me, you're awesome. Saved me quite some time

Answer (score 1):

Spring boot is expecting a logback file by default and you have provided log4j configuration.  If you add the log4j dependency you should find it works.  If you are using maven you can do so like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I already have the log4j dependency in my pom file

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

1. Is slf4j-log4j12 exclusion required?
2. I think that exclusion of spring-boot-starter-logging should be applied to spring-boot-starter.

That's not complete POM. I assume that spring-boot-starter is included, right?

If you remove slf4j-log4j12 exclusion and move spring-boot-starter-logging to spring-boot-starter your file should look like example from documentation.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
</dependency>
```